# How to properly point subdomain (w.example.com) to (ns1.w.example.com)

Tags: dns, subdomain

I want to point my subdomain (`w.example.com`) to (`ns1.w.example.com`)

```
NS  w.example.com directs to ns1.w.example.com.
A ns1.w.example.com directs to 192.0.2.139
```

---

```
>> dig w.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> w.example.com

;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 20571
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;w.example.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 195 msec
;; SERVER: 67.207.67.3#53(67.207.67.3)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 14 12:10:13 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Why is it breaking  DNS resolution & let me know the proper way to point my subdomain (`w.example.com`) to (`ns1.w.example.com`)

And what it is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Always use `dig` with `@` option to specify which nameserver you query otherwise when troubleshooting things you may get replies from some other nameserver than the one you are expecting. And you always need to first check things at authoritative nameservers for your zone, then at recursive ones.

Comment: A `SERVFAIL` indicate a major error and if it is on a nameserver you control you should first head to its logfiles and read there what is happening. It could also be DNSSEC related in which case add `+cd` to your `dig` invocation to make sure to disable DNSSEC for your first tests.

Comment: What do you mean by "point"? Either delegate a subzone to other nameservers (in which case you need proper `NS` records, as well as potential glues with `A` and `AAAA`) or just make a specific name resolve? In the second case you do not need delegation, as there is no one-to-one mapping between "dots" in a name and delegation. In the `example.com` zone you can without problems have `ns1.w.example.com IN A 192.0.2.139` directly without the need of any `NS` records (no delegation).

Comment: If you wish to use `dig` to analyse the problem try `dig +trace @8.8.8.8 w.example.com` and `dig +trace @8.8.8.8 ns1.w.example.com`, then you will see where it breaks (on condition that there's only one NS for w).

Comment: @Leo, No, `dig` with `@` and `+trace` at the same time does not make sense, as `@` will not be taken into account since `+trace` forces normal resolution process starting at root nameserver. What needs to be tested first is directly at authoritative nameserver and only later at recursive ones. And please remember that there is not only `8.8.8.8` in the world, but also `1.1.1.1`, `9.9.9.9`, `80.80.80.80` or `64.6.64.6` among many others. Anyway it is still preferable to test local recursive ones first, specially if you can control them (bypassing any cache issues, etc.)

Comment: "`@` will not be taken into account": in fact from documentation it is taken into account for the first query, to find out the root nameservers. So this is even more dangerous: if you asked a rogue recursive nameserver you could get a false list of root nameservers and then all subsequent queries will be meaningless. Just use `+trace` without anything, dig will use its correct internal root nameservers list.

Comment: Patrick; do you [a] understand the problem, truly wish [b] contribute to a solution?
Yes, the root part is irrelevant, it's just extra info for the OP to overview suspected and undesired behaviour.

Comment: Leo: [a] that is just rude and [b] see my comments, but the OP is both badly obfuscating and also not giving enough useful information (see my third comment). Also, since it is not related to programming, it is offtopic there. And if the "root part" is irrelevant, then why do you tell people to do `dig +trace @8.8.8.8` ? This is hugely misleading for at least two reasons, as explained. I will let you see if you understand them.

Comment: I advice `dig +trace @8.8.8.8` because you need a start point (in deed the root). Impossible "hugely misleading" as dig reports where it got answers. Thanks for reminding 80.80.80.80 but I'm 100% sure I knew it before you. There I disallow such queries, just like 9.9.9.9 later did. So those are fatal suggestion in this usecase. That could also happen local, and therfore I suggest to use 8.8.8.8 - and feel no need for multiple. Further I rather use a non-local resolver in case of someone not knowing how to delegate - and possible even mixing auth and rslv. While 8.8.8.8 usually tells reality.

Comment: It is silly to rely on any given outside nameserver, and insisting on presenting only one. Like probably thinking there is only one search engine in the world. Happy you think you knew 80.80.80.80 before me... if you think you have a way to ascertain that, but it is surely not games I want to play in. Anyway `dig +trace @8.8.8.8` remains useless and misleading. Specially if you add some attempts to explain that `8.8.8.8` is special in any way, which it isn't of course.

Comment: You keep twisting my words again: where did I state that 8.8.8.8 is special? Again, please play fair. I stated that q80 disallows and q9 -up until very recent- disallowed such queries resulting in getting the real root - which is what I wanted, to eliminate possible user configuration errors. 
Meanwhile it's remarkable you still didn't come up with your answer which truly is helpful and especially includes the hypothetical DNSSEC problem that you've added to OP's question. In deed plausible, but so far premature.

Answer (score 0):

At the zone of domain.com you need the delegation AND a glue record. Respectively the forlast and last record here:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
@      NS  auth.dns.example
@      NS  auth.dns.example
@      NS  auth.dns.example
...
w      NS  ns1.w
ns1.w  A   192.0.2.139
```

The glue record is "out-of-zone" data, needed to pre-indicate the address of that nameserver - as without that info a resolver can't guess it.

At the zone of w.example.com you need to have

```
$ORIGIN w.example.com.
@      NS  ns1
ns1    A   192.0.2.139
```

Comment: Why three NS records exactly the same?

Comment: The OP already said he has "A ns1.w.example.com directs to 192.0.2.139" so that is the glue, which does not explain then his problem (of course the useless obfuscation does not help)

Comment: The question was modified. So is my answer. So don't blame me for either.

Comment: The "three the same records" are to indicate the current auth.

Comment: Obfuscating is to keep it as clear as possible. The opposite is what makes is needless complex. And adding a irrelevant DNSSEC topic is even more useless.

Comment: "The question was modified. So is my answer. " Yes, because bad obfuscation is bad.

Comment: "The "three the same records" are to indicate the current auth. " No. Three identical NS records do not achieve anything. If you add `NS auth1.dns.example` and `NS auth2.dns.example` AND `NS auth3.dns.example` then it makes sense, but your answer with three `NS auth.dns.example` does not make any sense in the DNS...

Comment: "And adding a irrelevant DNSSEC topic is even more useless. " You obviously never had to debug DNS problems involving SERVFAIL which at the end of the day were related to DNSSEC. Since this is little know, I believe it is useful to mention it, for people obviously not experts in DNS configuration...

Comment: "And adding a irrelevant DNSSEC topic is even more useless." that is even funnier as a comment when you read this in dig manual: "+dnssec is also set when +trace is set to better emulate the default queries from a nameserver."

Comment: In dig sigchase is depricated and now off by default. Regardless, as OP didn't mention the use of DNSSEC at all, I think it's unrelated, and so IMHO you're trying to battle an irrelevant point. Good luck on that, but I'm going to ignore you untill it shows it is relevant.

Comment: Noone talked about `sigchase`, why do you write about it? You are accusing others to add irrelevant information, but I fail to see how `sigchase` is relevant to any part of above comments...